# Finding arc length of a circle from co-ordinate points

Tags: geometry

I am given three co-ordinate points of a circle O(Ox,Oy) as a center. Then two Points other points as A(Ax,Ay) & B(Bx,By). Now I have to find the arc length of that circle. Can you please help. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know the radius of the circle is $OA = \sqrt{(A_x-O_x)^2 + (A_y-O_y)^2}$. We can also find $AB = \sqrt{(A_x-B_x)^2 + (A_y-B_y)^2}$. Since we know $OA$, $OB$ (which is simply $OA$) and $AB$, we can find $\angle AOB$ using the [Cosine Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines). Once we have $\angle OAB$, then the arc length $ACB$ is equal to:

$$
\frac{\angle AOB}{360^{\circ}} \cdot 2\pi \cdot OA
$$

EDIT:

To obtain $\angle AOB$, we know that by Cosine Rule:

$$
cos \angle AOB = \frac{AB^2 - OA^2 - OB^2}{2}
$$

Thus $\angle AOB = cos^{-1}(\frac{AB^2 - OA^2 - OB^2}{2})$

Comment: ...Can you please describe finding the angle <AOB using cosine rule? I am not so good at this..

Comment: These are my Inputs: Ox - 5711 Oy-3044  Ax-477 Ay-2186  Bx-3257 By-7746
My Result should be: 6641.81699183

I can't find a solution with that. Specially finding on the theta.